# How to create a flat dictionary in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a text which I want to convert into a dictionary.

Here's the format of the text :

```
Apple 0
orange 5:
text1 : random text 
text2 : random text 
text3 : random text 
text4 : random text 
orange 6:
text1 : random text 
text2 : random text 
text3 : random text 
text4 : random text 

Apple 1
orange 12:
text1 : random text 
text2 : random text 
text3 : random text 
text4 : random text 
orange 13:
text1 : random text 
text2 : random text 
text3 : random text 
text4 : random text
```

I want to convert the dictionary something like this :

```
 dic_text = {'apple-0-orange-5-text1' : 'random text','apple-0-orange-5-text2' : 'random text','apple-0-orange-5-text3' : 'random text','apple-0-orange-5-text4' : 'random text','apple-0-orange-6-text1' : 'random text','apple-0-orange-6-text2' : 'random text','apple-0-orange-6-text3' : 'random text','apple-0-orange-6-text4' : 'random text','apple-1-orange-12-text1' : 'random text','apple-1-orange-12-text2' : 'random text','apple-1-orange-12-text3' : 'random text','apple-1-orange-12-text4' : 'random text','apple-1-orange-13-text1' : 'random text','apple-1-orange-13-text2' : 'random text','apple-1-orange-13-text3' : 'random text','apple-1-orange-13-text4' : 'random text'}
```

Can anyone tell me a generic way of making a dictionary something like above?

Comment: All the items are on single lines? So you can just iterate and be sure to obtain the first line containing the `apple 0`, then the `orange x` and finally the `textX : random text` parts?

Comment: Could you at least provide the code that you came up with, but that does not work properly?

Comment: Thanks guys, @Bakuriu answered my question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following information that you did not provide (please edit the question clarifying if this holds or not):

- That all the elements are on separate lines
- That all the elements take at most one line (so `random text` does *not* span multiple lines)
- That you want the keys in lowercase
- That you do *not* want to preserve the whitespace at beginning/end of the keys and `random text`
- `random text` *cannot* be just whitespace
- The "Apple X" line does *not* contain a `:`
- The "orange Y" line is the only kind of line that ends in `:` (plus eventually whitespace), so `random text` cannot end in `:`.
- After an "Apple X" line there is always an "orange Y" line (possibly after some empty lines).

Then you can do something like this:

```
def build_dict(iterable):
    result = {}
    main_key = None
    sub_key = None
    for line in iterable:
        # remove whitespace at beginning/end of line
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            # throw away empty lines
            continue
        elif ':' not in line:
            # we found an "Apple X" line, transform that into apple-X
            main_key = '-'.join(line.lower().split())
            sub_key = None
        elif line[-1] == ':':
            # we found an "orange X" line
            sub_key = '-'.join(line.lower().split())
        else:
            # add a `textX : random_text` element
            key, value = line.split(':')
            result['-'.join([main_key, sub_key, key.strip()])] = value.strip()
    return result
```

So you keep track of which `Apple X` value is in the `main_key`, and which `orange Y` value is in the `sub_key` and after that all lines `text X : random_text` are splitted on `:` and the three keys are combined and the value is saved in the dictionary.

If the assumptions I made do not hold then you have to handle things like multiline values etc, which depends on exactly the format of the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bakuriu.

Comment: could you also explain how can we make a dictionary inside a dictionary, if we were not to make a flat dictionary.